# Type 'Observable' is missing the following properties from type 'User'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

i want to get user data from firestore, but i get the error

> Type 'Observable' is missing the following properties from type 'User': email, emailVerified, uidts(2739)

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { User } from '../_classes/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  private dbPath = '/users';
  usersRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<User>;
  userData: User;

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.usersRef = db.collection(this.dbPath);
    this.getUserData();
  }

  private getUserData():User {
    const userId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).uid;

    ** Here comes the error **
    this.userData = this.usersRef.doc(userId).valueChanges();
  }

  get UserData():User {
    return this.userData;
  }
}
```

user.ts

```
export class User {
email: string;
emailVerified: boolean;
firstName?: string;
lastName?: string;
mitarbeiter?: boolean;
phone?: string;
uid: string;
```

}

[firebase firestore user example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJxcd.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used it myself, but according to [AngularFirestore docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md) `valueChanges()` returns an observable, not a value. Hence you get the error about type mismatch - you can't assign Observable to variable of type user. Instead, you need to either subscribe to the observable or operate on the observable itself - so it could be something along this way:

```
this.usersRef.doc(userId).valueChanges().subscribe(v => {
  this.userData = v;
});
```